# Solve the differential equation using separation of variables: $\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{3x+2y}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, euler-mascheroni-constant

I need to solve using the method of separation of variables. I got to this point but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track:

$$\frac{-1}{2e^{2y}} + C = \frac{e^{3x}}{3} + C$$

It looks like now I need to just solve for $y$ but how do I get rid of the $e$'s?

Comment: You don't need two $C$'s, one is enough (also the same $C$ shouldn't be used on both sides of the equation because they will then cancel).

Comment: Hint: After making the above corrections, apply $\ln$ to both sides to isolate $y$.

Comment: So after integrating both sides you only put a $C$ on one side?

Comment: $C$ is just a constant.  Two constants added together is another constant (practical conclusion, you should only have one $C$).  Alternately, you could have $C_1$ and $C_2$ (one for each side).

Comment: Fair enough. But I thought you can't take the natural log of a negative number? The left side is $(-1)$ and e is just a constant...although yes, it's being raised to the $2y$ so it could potentially end up making the left side positive....not sure.

Comment: You're right that you shouldn't take the log of a negative number, but you can manipulate the equation as $e^{-2y}=-\frac{2}{3}e^{3x}+C'$.  Now, since the LHS is always positive, this has a solution only when $C'$ is large enough for the RHS to be positive.  So, if you assume that $C'$ makes the RHS positive, then you can take the log of both sides.  Then the domain of your solution will not be all reals, but only those that make the RHS positive.

Comment: Ah, of course! Great explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. As mentioned in the comments you don't need a "$+C$" on both sides of the equation. Each integral contributes an additive constant, the two of which we can combine into a single constant.

Now you just need to solve for $y$. Start by isolating the only term with a $y$ in it.

$$\frac{-1}{2} e^{-2y} = \frac{1}{3}e^{3x}+C$$

$$ e^{-2y} = -\frac{2}{3}e^{3x}-2C$$

$$ e^{-2y} = -\frac{2}{3}e^{3x}+C$$

Notice that I just absorbed the $-2$ into a new definition of $C$.

Now we need to use logarithms to get rid of the $e$ on the left.

$$ -2y = \ln( -\frac{2}{3} e^{3x} + C) $$

$$ y = -\frac{1}{2}\ln( -\frac{2}{3} e^{3x} + C) .$$

And we are done. Each possible value of $C$ will correspond to a different solution to the differential equation with different initial data.